# Upgrading from Windows 10 Home to Pro from W-7

Tags: windows, windows-10, operating-systems, windows-10-upgrade, product-key

I am on Windows 7 Professional. I am going to do the upgrade to windows 10 with that media installer. I am assuming it will put me with the Home edition. If I put in my windows 7 pro key, will it upgrade windows 10 to pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am assuming it will put me with the Home edition.

Windows 7 Professional can only be upgraded to Windows 8 Professional, Windows 8.1 Professional, or Windows 10 Professional.

> If I put in my windows 7 pro key, will it upgrade windows 10 to pro?

The Windows 10 free upgrade offer has long expired.  If you wish to upgrade to Windows 10 you will have to purchase a Windows 10 Professional license.

The only legitimate way the Windows 7 Professional license could be used today is if you had taken advantage of the free upgrade offer in the past.

Answer (score -2):

Yes if you have a Pro key you can enter it under Start Menu > Settings > Updates and Security > Activation and it should change it.